# prolog reasoning about constraints

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to use Prolog to reason about constraints and then query the knowledgebase to pass these constraints on to a solver (can't use clpfd).

```
%a first example would be constrainsquare(Row,Col,Val)
constrainsquare(1,1,3).
constrainsquare(1,2,2).
```

and I can then query all constraints using something like `bagof/3`. This is not statisfactory because I also want to be able to write

```
 constrainsquare(3,4,8):-constrainsquare(3,3,7).
```

The ability to say that if the solution has a `7` at position `3,3`; it necessarily has an `8` at position `3,4`.
Now you can no longer gather all constraints using something like `bagof/3`.

How would you do this ideomatically in prolog?

Note that I cannot simply do

```
constrainsquare(L) :-
  member(cs(1,1,3),L),
  member(cs(1,2,2),L),
  member(cs(3,4,8),L),
  member(cs(3,3,7),L).
```

because I'm receiving new facts about the solution periodically and cannot alter existing facts.

At the moment I'm thinking about using a list of constraints and doing something like

```
info(cell(1,1,3)).
info(cell(1,2,2)).
constrainsquare(I,[I]).
partialinfo(cell(3,4,8),cell(3,3,7)).
....
```

and then query it by running bagoff to obtain `[cell(1,1,3)],[cell(1,2,2)]...` and then folding/appending to `[cell(1,1,3),cell(1,2,2)]` but this feels a bit 'meh'. I want to know the "proper" way.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you were expecting to call `bagof/3` and why it doesn't work? If I assert facts `constrainsquare(1,1,3).`, `constrainsquare(1,2,2).`, `constrainsquare(3,3,7).` and the rule `constrainsquare(3,4,8):-constrainsquare(3,3,7).` and query, `bagof([A,B,C], constrainsquare(A,B,C), L)`, I get all of the expected solutions listed in `L`. So I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: Ah yes, if you assert constrainsquare(3,3,7) first, then that rule will work. The issue here is that the real solution doesn't need to have a 7 at position 3,3. The only information given is that if there is a 7 there, there necessarily also has to be an 8 at position 3,4. I can't find an 'elegant' workaround and this usually means that I'm doing something fundamentally the wrong way, so I'm asking what the right way is. :)

Comment: I guess I'm not following what you man by *gathering all constraints* with `bagof/3`. `bagof/3` doesn't gather constraints, but rather it gathers known solutions assuming the currently asserted facts and rules.

Comment: What you could do is say (im on mobile, don't see how i can do code tags) "hasto(cell(1,2,3)). hasto(cell(3,4,5))." And then with bagof you can obtain a list containing all requirements [cell(1,2,3),cell(3,4,5)]. So i could query my knowledgebase to obtain the constrains to pass on to a solver.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm not very clear in my question, but I'm not sure what I can change to make it better. All I want is to supply facts about the solution, including conditional facts, and then gather what the possible solutions can be.

Comment: I've read through your question a few times. One small point of confusion is your terminology. You use the word *constraints* when I think you really mean *facts* in Prolog. A *constraint* is usually in the form of part of a rule. For example, `N > 1` is a *constraint* (it limits `N` in some way). But `foo(1, 2, 7).` is a *fact*. The asserted term, `constrainsquare(I, [I]).` seems to be a constraint, although it's hard to tell what it means. When you mention collecting *constraints* you really mean collecting a list of *facts* (or more specifically, a list of *bound Prolog terms*)?

Comment: Ah yes, I do mean facts when talking about constraints. I try to model something sudoku-like, so when I have the prolog _fact_ cellvalue(1,2,4) then all this really means behind the scenes is that the sudoku solution is _constrained_ because a 4 has to appear at (1,2). My end goal would therefore be to collect a list of prolog _facts_ but I'd also like to use conditional rules saying "if a 4 appears at 1,2 then an 8 has to appear at 3,5".

Comment: So for the facts/rules "there is a 4 at 1,2; if there is an 8 at position 2,3 then there is a 9 at 4,5" I'd like to gather the following two lists: "[4 at 1,2; 8 at 2,3; 9 at 4,5] , [4 at 1,2; no 8 at 2,3]"

Comment: Your example of facts and rules, stated as Prolog, would be `cs(4, 1, 2).` and `cs(9, 4, 5) :- cs(8, 2, 3)`. So, it isn't necessarily true that `cs(8, 2, 3)`. Thus, it isn't necessarily true that `cs(9, 4, 5)`. If you query `cs(X, Y, Z)` in that case, you'll only get `cs(4, 1, 2)` as provable, which corresponds to your second example response (`[4 at 1,2; no 8 at 2,3]` noting that "no 8 at 2,3" is the same as not asserting that 8 at 2,3). To get your first result, you have to postulate (assert) `cs(8, 2, 3).` as a fact. Prolog doesn't know it as a possible fact without it being asserted.

Comment: I get that, but I wanted some kind of workaround. I should probably convert the claim "if X then Y" into "either [X and Y] [not X]" and create a bunch of facts constrainsolution(cs(8,2,3)). constrainsolution(cs(5,3,2)). and query the knowledgebase using findall, to find out what constraints have been imposed on the solution and pass that on to the solver.

Comment: I guess maybe I'm still having trouble following. So you want a set of facts and rules, `cs/3`. But then you want to "postulate" sets of facts or constraints using a number of `constrainslution(cs(_,_,_))`? Or perhaps a list of them? Like a "what if" scenario? For example, if you have the basic `cs/3` rules and facts, but wanted a what-if, you could write, `what_if(ListOfPostulates, Results)`?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it any other way. I want to model a game which is one big puzzle. I periodically get new information about said puzzle which I want to input as facts in prolog. This information corresponds with constraints on the solution of the puzzle. I also have a solver, that can be used to solve the game when I have enough constraints, when the solution is unique. I can query the knowledgebase and pass the result of those queries onto the solver.

Comment: Can't you just assert the new facts and run the query? Then retract them (if you need to) if you don't want them persistent?

Comment: Yes, of course I can assert new facts and run a query. The entire question is on how I would ideomatically go about doing this. If I know that cell 1,1 has value 3 (a fact I want to input) and if I know that cell 2,2 has value 3 if cell 2,1 has value 2 (another fact I want to input), how do I in the end gather [[cell(1,1,3),cell(2,2,3),cell(2,1,2)],[cell(1,1,3),notcell(2,2,3)]]. What query should I run, how should I design this system? I don't understand how this comment isn't pretty much copy-pasting the original question.

Comment: Are the lists inside of your big list different fact scenarios? In other words, you want to run the query separately for each of them? And are the facts "cumulative", meaning that since `cell(2,1,2)` appeared in the first list, it remains "true" even for the second list unless a `notcell(2,1,2)` is encountered?

Comment: Yes, they're different fact scenarios. I can of course implement a "whatif" constraint, but I think you'd end up running into problems rather quickly (for example, what if I end up needing more complicated constructions, whatif's within watiffs? I don't think it's a 'nice' solution). So I pretty much have to use different fact scenarios (I'll also be using problog instead of prolog, with probabilistic constraints and therefore also probabilistic fact scenarios). I've reread your last comment about asserting/retracting, didn't know those things were also prolog functions, misinterpreted that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you had query, we'll call it `Q`, that you wished to run on a set of hypothetical facts. We'll call the set of facts, `Facts`. You could write a predicate which would run the query on those facts dynamically as follows:

```
what_if_query(Q, Facts) :-
    maplist(assertz, Facts),
    call(Q),
    maplist(retract, Facts).
```

If `Q` takes one argument for results, `R`, then we could write:

```
what_if_query(Q, Facts, R) :-
    maplist(assertz, Facts),
    call(Q, R),
    maplist(retract, Facts).
```

Then, if you had a list of scenarios of facts, you could write:

```
what_if_scenarios(Scenarios, Q, Results) :-
    maplist(what_if_query(Q), Scenarios, Results).
```

A "fact" can be any assertable Prolog term, and so could also be a rule: `(Head :- P1, P2, ..., Pn)`. For example, your list of "facts" could be:

```
[cs(1,1,3), cs(1,2,2), (cs(3,4,8) :- cs(3,3,7))]
```

Comment: I honestly had no idea that assertz and retract existed. Can be used to do pretty much exactly what I want, thanks for putting this much time in my confusing question :p

Comment: @camel - when you enter a Prolog program, you are *statically* "asserting" terms that define the facts and rules. Prolog also allows *dynamic* asserting and retraction of terms. If you browse the Prolog pre-defined predicates in the manual, you'll find lots of interesting predicates there. :)